# cross-domain iframe javascript click event (scroll up)

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain

Setup:
I have website A and B.
Website B has a scroll-up button and is iframed inside of site A.
 A and B are two different domains.

I've tried everything including window.postMessage and nothing is working.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's too vague. Create a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *"I've tried everything including window.postMessage and nothing is working."* and, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: to have the button scroll me to the top of the page.

Answer (score 0):

This lib has a function to allow an iframe to scroll the parent page.

https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer